Problems applying the Greens function method to calculate exchange energies with quantum-espresso and exchanges-master codes
I am trying to calculate exchange constants for crystalline Nickel (Ni) compounds using the Greens function method by Dm M. Korotin et al.  Phys. Rev. B  91, 224405 (2015).  This is accomplished with a combination of quantum-espresso and a code-named exchanges-master.  However when I download exchanges-master from https://github.com/dkorotin/exchanges and put it in my home directory the exchanges-master will not compile (using command make) because of errors like undefined reference to ‘omp_get_thread_num’.
For more specifics the computer I am using is new:

It is a HP envy with a i9 intel core and 64 Gbytes of memory.
The gfortran code is the latest version GNU Fortran
(Ubuntu11.4.0-1ubuntu1-22.04) 11.4.0).
The latest versions of lapack and blas are also installed.

The only preparation one is instructed to do on exchanges-master directory is to designate gfortran and the lapack packages in the Makefile using the vim editor. After doing so, one is ready to compile with make, which is supposed to produce exchanges.x which does the Greens function calculations. However, instead, one gets:
(i) gfortran   -o exchanges.x exchanges.o parameters.o general.o iomodule.o find_nnbrs.o green_function.o -L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/ -llapack -lblas
(ii) /usr/bin/ld: exchanges.o: in function `MAIN__':
(iii) /mnt/c/Users/adolp/exchanges-master/exchanges.f90:61: undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads_'
 `compute_g_._omp_fn.0':
(iv) /mnt/c/Users/adolp/exchanges-master/green_function.f90:23: undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
(v) /usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/adolp/exchanges-master/green_function.f90:23: undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
(vi) /usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/adolp/exchanges-master/green_function.f90:23: undefined reference to `GOMP_barrier'
(vii)/usr/bin/ld: green_function.o: in function `compute_g_':
(viii) /mnt/c/Users/adolp/exchanges-master/green_function.f90:21: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:28: exchanges.x] Error 1
Note the compilation is OK with our choices made in the Makefile (see line (i) above).  The difficulty begins when it compiles the greens function calculation with 
‘/usr/bin/id: exchanges.oi in function  ‘MAIN_’

All of the errors are concerned with OMP and GOMP. One might first think the solution is to compile Quantum expresso by disabling parallel processing and openmp. However, I have compiled QE every way. The ‘exchanges-master’ appears to be quite independent in operation from quantum espresso. The only role for QE is to provide the input data for exchanges.x which is the working package one obtains from exchanges-master after its make compilation.
The files where the errors occur are in the exchanges-master directory and their location (i.e. file line)  is given with the errors listed in (ii) to (viii) above. Since these files are needed to perform the calculations, one cannot avoid the commands given in their code related to OMP and GOMP. It seems the only thing one can do is make their use well defined. However, there are no instructions regarding how to do that. Another possible and perhaps more likely solution would be to use earlier versions of exchanges-master which likely did not make reference to OMP and GOMP. However earlier versions are not listed on Github.

It appears to be sufficient to add -fopenmp to the linker command as well as to the compiler command - either by adding it to the LIBS variable (as in the suggested parameters under #gfortan Mac Os) or - more formally correct I think - via the LFLAGS variable:
# gfortran linux
 FC = gfortran 
 FFLAGS = -fopenmp -Og -O2 -g
 LIBS = -llapack -lblas
 LFLAGS = -fopenmp

(you don't need -L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/ if you have installed LAPACK/BLAS from the Ubuntu repositories). From man gfortran (emphasis mine):
       -fopenmp
           Enable   the  OpenMP  extensions.   This  includes  OpenMP  "!$omp"
           directives in free form and "c$omp", *$omp and  "!$omp"  directives
           in  fixed form, "!$" conditional compilation sentinels in free form
           and "c$", "*$" and "!$" sentinels in fixed form, and  when  linking
           arranges  for  the  OpenMP  runtime  library  to be linked in.  The
           option -fopenmp implies -frecursive.
Then
 $ make
gfortran  -c -fopenmp -Og -O2 -g -o parameters.o parameters.f90
gfortran  -c -fopenmp -Og -O2 -g -o general.o general.f90
gfortran  -c -fopenmp -Og -O2 -g -o iomodule.o iomodule.f90
gfortran  -c -fopenmp -Og -O2 -g -o find_nnbrs.o find_nnbrs.f90
gfortran  -c -fopenmp -Og -O2 -g -o green_function.o green_function.f90
gfortran  -c -fopenmp -Og -O2 -g -o exchanges.o exchanges.f90
gfortran  -fopenmp -o exchanges.x exchanges.o parameters.o general.o iomodule.o find_nnbrs.o green_function.o -llapack -lblas
 $ 
 $ ./exchanges.x

     ------------------------------------------------------------------
                           Program EXCHANGES                           
      for calculation of exchange parameters of the Heisenberg model.  

     Please cite "D. M. Korotin et al., Phys. Rev. B 91, 224405 (2015)"
         in publications or presentations arising from this work.      
     ------------------------------------------------------------------

        We are using the model with the exchange term defined as:      

                        H = \sum_ij J_{ij} e_i e_j,                    

      where e_i,j are unit vectors and sum runs once over ions pairs   

     ------------------------------------------------------------------


     Running in   1 threads

^C


To Steel driver,   Thank you very much for your answer.  It solves all my problems.    Now the compilation works like a charm and I have my exchanges.x which is the package that calculates the exchange parameter.  I also thank you for explaining the role of the linker command.
